# Timescaledb extension for postgresql V.13 Beta 3 (windows)

Tags: windows, postgresql

I am using PostgreSQL 13 Beta 3 on (windows.8/*64bit). I want to add timescaledb extension. My "postgresql.conf" directory is correct but every time i try to install the extension, I get a message which is attached.
I had also changed Environment Address to "C:\Program Files\PostgreSQL\13\bin" [The address of pg_config.exe", but nothing changed. Is there a possibility that i have to use from postgreSQL V.12 as mentioned in the installation instruction?  [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jXN4b.png)
Thank you in advance for your help and guide

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You cannot to do it. Timescale doesn't support Postgres 13 yet. Postgres 13 was not releases yet - there only test releases are available.

PostgreSQL extensions should be compiled for specific Postgres major version. So you cannot to use timescale for Postgres 12 or Postgres 11 for Postgres 13.

Comment: Thank You So Much Pavel, thanks For Your Time and care about my question.

Answer (score 0):

It's not ready yet. It's expected on  the upcoming TimescaleDB `v2.0.1`. Read more at their release notes: https://docs.timescale.com/latest/release-notes.